# Angular + Laravel 5.1: Saving a $resource with related objects

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-5.1, propel, ngresource

I got lost in this situation and would like to receive some feedback/advice on how to do this.

I'm building an application with a Laravel 5.1 back-en and a AngularJS frontend. Both are new to me but I love them so far. For my database communication I'm using Propel 2.

So I got my Order object in Laravel set-up with Propel which is working fine. To use this model in Angular I created a resource factory.

```
angular.module('flex')
    .factory('Order', ['$resource', 'Address', 'Person', function($resource, Address, Person)
    {
        var Order = $resource('/restful/shop/order/:id', {id: '@id'}, {
            query: {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: true,
                transformResponse: function(data, header)
                {
                    var jsonData = angular.fromJson(data);
                    var orders = [];

                    angular.forEach(jsonData, function(item)
                    {
                        var order = new Order(item);
                        orders.push(order);
                    });

                    return orders;
                }
            },
            update: {
                method: 'PUT',
                params: {id: '@Id'},
            }
        });

        Order.prototype.Person = null;

        Order.prototype.getAddresses = function() {};
        Order.prototype.getOrderProducts = function() {};
        Order.prototype.getPayments = function() {};
        Order.prototype.getPerson = function()
        {
            if (this.Person != null)
                return this.Person;

            var OrderObject = this;
            this.Person = {};

            Person.get({id: this.PersonId}, function (response)
            {
                OrderObject.Person = response;
            });
            return this.Person;
        };
        Order.prototype.getShippingAddress = function() {};

        return Order;
    }])
```

As you can see this resource has a function getPerson() which loads a person object from another resource factory.

```
angular.module('flex')
    .factory('Person', function($resource)
    {
        var Person = $resource('/restful/common/person/:id', {id: '@id'}, {
            query: {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: true,
                transformResponse: function(data, header)
                {
                    var jsonData = angular.fromJson(data);
                    var persons = [];

                    angular.forEach(jsonData, function(item)
                    {
                        var person = new Person(item);
                        persons.push(person);
                    });

                    console.log(persons);

                    return persons;
                }
            }
        });

        return Person;
    })
```

So far everything works great. I can load and display my orders and load the person object with this and also display the data from this object.

The issue comes when I want to store updates. If I call Order.$update() the put request is made to my Laravel update action.

```
public function update($id, Request $request)
{
    // Check for orderI
    // Load order
    $order = OrderQuery::create()
        ->findPk($id);

    // Iterate data
    foreach ($request->all() as $key => $value)
    {
        echo 'set' . $key . "\n";
        $order->{'set' . $key}($value);
    }

    // Save object
    $order->save();
}
```

Here comes the problem. setPerson on the Order objects expects an Person object but an simple object with just parameters is sent. I could just skip input that is not string or integer but what if I updated details in the person too. I'd be nice if the Person would be updated too but I don't know what is the best way to do this.

My options but I'm hoping there is a better way:

- Write an custom save function on the Angular side
- Extend the Laravel update action to detect objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"Your options should always segregate routes with concerns. If it does not matter to the application keep a single route which does both."* I cannot see your setPerson or how you are calling order.person in angular (along with what data you are passing)? You can keep everything in one route but make sure you are using correct methods to do the work.

"Here comes the problem. setPerson on the Order objects expects an Person object but an simple object with just parameters is sent. I could just skip input that is not string or integer but what if I updated details in the person too. I'd be nice if the Person would be updated too but I don't know what is the best way to do this." Can you explain this more?

Comment: The person object is used like {{ order.getPerson().NameFirst }}

Comment: When the data is sent to the Laravel server order.Person is an object like {Id: 6, ContactEmail: "xxx", ContactFacebook: null, ContactPhone: "xxx",…}. Using propels $order->setPerson() throws an error since this expects an Person object.

Comment: Right. AngularJS has no controls of your PHP code. Are you sending the order.Person along with the $http/$resource request method - whether post/patch/update? If your PHP code needs the object specified then pass it. If you are; then handle the request appropriately. I believe there is a sync issue. Not much I can figure out with whats happening with your PHP code.

Comment: I see no code which specifies your setPerson and where you are doing setPerson. If you are handling a relational DB you dont need to duplicate details. Just a id is cleaner. Your PHP code needs to handle that backend business logic. Check what you are updating and why? Don forget the fundamentals of data dups.

Comment: Thanks. I did it that way now. The order object in angular only has the id of the person object and I created separate objects/controllers for the person. In the angular object there is an function getPerson() which will load the person from laravel with the new controller.

Comment: Ok. I will strongly recommend putting the functions or business logic to services or factories and keep controller slim. If you want to trigger them during onload then use your ui-router's resolve method or trigger a onload event capture event listener through your angular app.